# How do I write a code to copy data from one sheet to another when "x" is found and not duplicate

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to do a macro that will copy data from one sheet titled Used Car Log onto another sheet titled Used Pending but only when an x is found in column L on the Used Car Log. If x is found in column L then I need all data in cells B through K (on that row) to be copied onto Used Pending into corresponding columns B through K. I need it to find the next blank row to insert it into and I need it to not duplicate any data. Any help would be appreciated! I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Can you show some code you have so far?

Comment: well that is the thing, I have no code. this would be my first time doing this and I've researched it long enough now to realize it's a little beyond my purview.

Comment: http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic1.htm you're not going to become a programmer over night, so there's no sense in the hurry =)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I have no doubt it takes years to learn your craft....so thank goodness I only want to learn a very small part of it to fit some very specific needs. Appreciate the help I'm checking out the link now.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do exactly what you ask for, but not more than that. It sets the value in the L column to xx (instead of just x) to not copy the data twice, and it assumes that the x-es in the L column are in order, which of course could be a false assumption.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim run As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
run = True
While run
    If Worksheets("Used Car Log").Range("L" + CStr(i)).Value = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Used Pending").Range("B" + CStr(i) + ":K" + CStr(i)).Value = Worksheets("Used Car Log").Range("B" + CStr(i) + ":K" + CStr(i)).Value
        'Mark the value as copied by setting the value in column L as xx
        Worksheets("Used Car Log").Range("L" + CStr(i)).Value = "xx"
    ElseIf Worksheets("Used Car Log").Range("L" + CStr(i)).Value = "" Then
        run = False
    End If

    i = i + 1
Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for writing that code but for some reason when I try to run the macro nothing happens. Not sure what I'm doing incorrect but I believe I went through the correct process.

Comment: Did you add a button to your spreadsheet, right-click it, and select "Assign macro"?

Comment: Another way (the quick and dirty): Open the code window (Alt+F11), add a new module (right click on VBAProject and select New->Module), paste this code, make sure your cursor is placed in the function and hit F5, should do the trick.

Comment: I did all of the above and when clicking the button or doing the quick and dirty way no data was transferred. I appreciate all of your help on this but it looks like I'm not going to be able to accomplish this particular automated task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the IF function?

For example, in the **Used Pending** sheet, you could use a formula like this in cell **A1**:

```
=IF(UsedCarLog!L1="x",UsedCarLog!A1,"")
```

Then, delete all empty rows in the **Used Pending** sheet.

Comment: I was wrong that could work, but what about when it returns a 0 in the fields that are blank. How can I get it to not show 0 or false when there is nothing to copy over yet?

Comment: There are 3 parts to an IF statement: the test, what to put if the test passes, and what to put if the test fails. Each of these parts is seperated by a comma. In the example above, the last part is just "", which means that a blank is returned if the test fails. This will keep the cell empty, instead of having a 0 or FALSE.

Comment: Alright that worked for just the transfer but for the overall functionality of the spreadsheet it won't do. I think I'm going to have to continue looking for help with code. Yikes. Thank you for this answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FindAndMove()

Dim LastrowUP As Integer
Dim LastrowCarLog As Integer
Dim RowNumber As Integer

LastrowCarLog = Sheets("Used Car Log").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Sheets("Used Car Log").Range("L1:L" & LastrowCarLog)
 If c.text = "x" Then
 RowNumber = c.Row
 LastrowUP = Sheets("Used Pending").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 Sheets("Used Car Log").Range("B" & RowNumber & ":" & "K" & RowNumber).Copy
 Sheets("Used Pending").Range("B" & LastrowUP + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End If
Next c

Sheets("Used Pending").Range("B1:K" & LastrowUP + 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 10), Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Paste into a new module in the VB editor. Then, create a button on your spreadsheet, right-click, select "Assign macro" and select FindAndMove

Comment: when clicking the button I assigned the macro to it gives me a Run-Time error '1004': This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized. When looking at the spreadsheet it has the row with the data (and required x) highlighted from the first to last column we wanted copied. But that is all it does. If I hit debug on the message it takes me to the code in the macro where this line is pointed out and highlighted.  Sheets("Used Pending").Range("B" & LastrowUP + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues Any further help @EricJ would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest unmerging any merged cells in your workbook. Can you unmerge all your cells? This code works on a sample workbook I've created that contains no merged cells.

Comment: This worked. I actually copied these sheets into a new workbook just to be sure I didn't mess up the original beyond repair and removed all merged cells. it works now! However, the issue Torgrim addressed in a previous answer of "duplicate copying" is a problem. If you add new data to the used car log and run the macro it will copy the new data over but also duplicate copy the others. any suggestions?

Comment: Ya, I'm sorry I missed that in your original post. I'll get that corrected for you soon, shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: I've edited the code above to remove duplicate rows. Give it a try and let me know! Remember, no merged cells!

Comment: The new code kind of messes a few things up. perhaps there is a way to change the x (kind of the concept the guy mentioned below) to a xx or something. I Tested it out in your original code (the one that worked perfect) by manually changing the x to xx and then adding a new line with an x and it only found the new one and copied it over while leaving all prior data as is. Your opinion? If I have to be manual about changing the x I will but if it can be automated that would be fantastic.

Comment: There must be something you're not telling me about your spreadsheet or what you're wanting to do. The above code will copy all rows that have an "x" in column L to the Used Pending sheet. After all data is copied to Used Pending, it looks at B:K and removes the duplicate rows from that sheet. Does this sound like what you're after? Because this works in the workbook I've created. Is the Used Pending sheet blank to start out with? It would be helpful if you could post a sample workbook